# WPF DatagridComboboxColumn Validation Error

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a datagrid, with ComboBox as a column. I am able to load the DataGrid and Get the proper values in the combobox, but for some reason, everytime i click and update the value of the combobox, a redbox apears and the whole Datagrid freezes not allowing me to make any further updates.

I don't have specific validation errors.

Here is a sample code

```
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dgvFactor" Margin="3"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="True" SelectionMode="Single" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbxfactor" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding id_measure}" Header="Medida de Conversion" Width="200"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding factor}"  Header="Valor" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

and the code behind looks like this

```
    cbxfactor.SelectedValuePath = "id"
    cbxfactor.DisplayMemberPath = "measure"
    cbxfactor.ItemsSource = appVM.MeasurementList
```

So again, everything shows up fine, but when I start to edit, thats when I run into problems!

Thanks in advance

I found this error...

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '2' (type 'Int32'). BindingExpression:Path=id_price_list; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=66577575); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: No se puede convertir ByteConverter desde System.Int32.
```

Comment: Please provide the interface of the object behind `appVM.MeasurementList`

Comment: Its a basic DataTable whose DefaultView gets exposed as MeasurementList (dataview).

Comment: Yes but my guess is that the reason for your problems is in the implementation of that data table. Maybe the writing fails. Maybe the reference to the fields that are edited are the problem.

Comment: this is the error i got...System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '2' (type 'Int32'). BindingExpression:Path=id_price_list; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=66577575); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: No se puede convertir ByteConverter desde System.Int32.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem 2 days ago. I just modified the

```
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding id_measure}"
```

with

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding id_measure}"
```

And it started working.